# correct syntax for VB web service code sql insert FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having some trouble getting the correct syntax for a bit if code. I am using vb to insert data into a db and outputting the data as XML, here is the code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function addTrack(ByVal tTitle As String, ByVal tAlbum As String, ByVal tGenre As String) As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MARTIN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mp3_playlists;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Tracks (trackTitle, trackAlbum, trackGenre) VALUES ('" & tTitle & "', '" & tAlbum & "', '" & tGenre & "') FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS"
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim track As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    conn.Close()
    Return track
End Function
```

The code is for a ASP.NET web service, when I click invoke on the website i get the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'. If I remove FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS everything works find, db updates but I dont get the data to output as XML. I think the issue is with 
the brackets required for the insert values because this issue does not occur if the SQL statement is a SELECT statement which has no brackets but i just cant figure out the correct syntax, thanks for your help

Comment: What do you want to return back to the client? Does `Insert` return a value? Normally it doesnt, unless you select @@RowCount or something scalar like that.

Answer (score 0):

FOR XML AUTO is only used for SELECT statements. So, the issue is not your insert statement, it is your select statement, whereever that is.